# Htaccess block incoming urls except one

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this on my `htaccess`:

`RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

- and I want add i new URLS like `faq.html` how do i do that ? basically wanna block all incoming URLS except index and `faq.html`

any ideas ? Thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by `incoming URLS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below above your RewriteRule will not rewrite if it is an existing(f)ile or (d)irectory.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

You can also do:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/faq.html"
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} "faq.html"
```

Just checked the last two lines of code, they are not valid...

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /faq.html
```

Comment: so just add a new line code like this? RewriteCond %{faq.html} !-f

Comment: Try: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} "/faq.html"` that should work. The code I gave above allows for all existing files and directories to be ignored. the code above will allow faq.html only to be ignored. The code you just used is saying don't rewrite if "faq.html" is not a file. You want to compare the request uri to an existing file.

Comment: @JohnyDerp `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /faq.html` is valid. Sorry.